# Can C++ classes with deleted methods be trivially copyable?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

I want class B to inherit all but a few methods of class A (which is assumed to be trivially copyable), and still be trivially copyable. In C++11 I can delete methods. Take for example:

```
class A { // trivially copyable
   // private stuff here
public:
   A& operator += (const A&);
   // other public stuff here
};

class B: public A {
public:
   B& operator += (const A&) = delete;
};
```

Is B trivially copyable? I know there are issues regarding the deletion of special methods, but the compound assignment is not a special method (right?).

Comment: You may check yourself with `std::is_trivially_copyable`.

Comment: Thanks, @Jarod42. I'm using GCC v4.8.2, where std::is_trivially_copyable isn't implemented yet... (at least that is the error message I get whenever I try to call it using <type_traits>). I would have use it otherwise. Btw, do you know of any compilers where it might be implemented?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, `B` is trivially copyable - regardless of what you do to non-special member functions.

> **N3337, §9/6**:
>
> A *trivially copyable class* is a class that: 
> — has no non-trivial
>   copy constructors (12.8),
>  — has no non-trivial move constructors
>   (12.8),
>  — has no non-trivial copy assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8),
>   — has no non-trivial move assignment operators (13.5.3, 12.8), and
>  —
>   has a trivial destructor (12.4).

> but the compound assignment is not a special method (right?)

No, it's not.

> **N3337, §12/1**:
>
> The default constructor (12.1), copy constructor and copy assignment
>   operator (12.8), move constructor and move assignment operator (12.8),
>   and destructor (12.4) are *special member functions*.

Comment: Thank you! This fact helps a lot. I suspected it, but I didn't know if some specification somewhere in the standard regarding the =delete feature would prevent memcpy to be used in such derived types.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're on the right track--if A is trivially copyable and B is derived from A and simply deletes some regular methods (or operators), B will be trivially copyable too.

Comment: Thank you! This allows me to safely derive a fixed-size unitary matrix class from a fixed-size general matrix class (unitary matrices are not closed under + or -), while keeping data contiguity.