# Why are mutexes and condition variables trivially copyable?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++14

[LWG 2424](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4460.html) discusses the undesirable status of atomics, mutexes and condition variables as [trivially copyable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/TriviallyCopyable) in C++14. I appreciate that a fix is [already lined up](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1734), but [`std::mutex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/mutex), [`std::condition variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) et al. appear to have non-trivial destructors. For example:

> **30.4.1.2.1 Class mutex [thread.mutex.class]**
>
> ```
> namespace std {
>   class mutex {
>   public:
>     constexpr mutex() noexcept;
>     ~mutex(); // user-provided => non-trivial
>
>     …
>   }
> }
> ```

Shouldn't this disqualify them as trivially copyable?

Comment: Looks like this is just something Howard said during the discussion, possibly without thinking it through?

Comment: Are you sure `std::mutex` is trivially copyable?  Per the standard they copy constructor and the copy assignment are both marked as `delete`.

Comment: @NathanOliver That's the point of LWG 1734. (Although you are right - `mutex` is not trivially copyable. Because its destructor is not trivial.)

Comment: @NathanOliver: A deleted special member function is still technically a trivial one.

Comment: @NathanOliver GCC seems to think that is it.

Comment: @NicolBolas Interesting.  I did not know that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Either it was my mistake, or I was misquoted, and I honestly don't recall which.

However, I have this very strongly held advice on the subject:

> Do not use `is_trivial` nor `is_trivially_copyable`!  EVER!!!

Instead use one of these:

```
is_trivially_destructible<T>
is_trivially_default_constructible<T>
is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>
is_trivially_copy_assignable<T>
is_trivially_move_constructible<T>
is_trivially_move_assignable<T>
```

Rationale:

**tldr:**  See this [excellent question and correct answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25830995/576911)

No one (including myself) can remember the definition of `is_trivial` and `is_trivially_copyable`.  And if you do happen to look it up, and then spend 10 minutes analyzing it, it may or may not do what you intuitively think it does.  And if you manage to analyze it correctly, the CWG may well change its definition with little or no notice and invalidate your code.

Using `is_trivial` and `is_trivially_copyable` is playing with fire.

However these:

```
is_trivially_destructible<T>
is_trivially_default_constructible<T>
is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>
is_trivially_copy_assignable<T>
is_trivially_move_constructible<T>
is_trivially_move_assignable<T>
```

do exactly what they sound like they do, and are not likely to ever have their definition changed.  It may seem overly verbose to have to deal with each of the special members individually.  But it will pay off in the stability/reliability of your code.  And if you must, package these individual traits up into a custom trait.

**Update**

For example, clang & gcc compile this program:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
void
test()
{
    using namespace std;
    static_assert(!is_trivial<T>{}, "");
    static_assert( is_trivially_copyable<T>{}, "");
    static_assert( is_trivially_destructible<T>{}, "");
    static_assert( is_destructible<T>{}, "");
    static_assert(!is_trivially_default_constructible<T>{}, "");
    static_assert(!is_trivially_copy_constructible<T>{}, "");
    static_assert( is_trivially_copy_assignable<T>{}, "");
    static_assert(!is_trivially_move_constructible<T>{}, "");
    static_assert( is_trivially_move_assignable<T>{}, "");
}

struct X
{
    X(const X&) = delete;
};

int
main()
{
    test<X>();
}
```

Note that `X` **is** trivially copyable, but **not** trivially copy constructible.  To the best of my knowledge, this is conforming behavior.

VS-2015 currently says that `X` is **neither** trivially copyable nor trivially copy constructible.  I believe this is wrong according to the current spec, but it sure matches what my common sense tells me.

If I needed to `memcpy` to *uninitialized* memory, I would trust `is_trivially_copy_constructible` over `is_trivially_copyable` to assure me that such an operation would be ok.  If I wanted to `memcpy` to *initialized* memory, I would check `is_trivially_copy_assignable`.

Comment: From the horse's mouth! Thanks for the advice. I didn't realize those traits were in C++17. Just to be clear, you consider the standard to be mandating a user-provided destructor in the case of `std::mutex` and company? I ask because the other answers do not seem to think this is the case.

Comment: Yes, but this is a fuzzy area in the standard.  The mutex spec was not designed with the rules about "trivial" in mind.  Such a trait may change.  But in summary, I don't think what the spec says regarding whether mutex is trivially copyable important, because the definition of "trivially copyable" is both bizarre and subject to change.  More important are questions like:  Can mutex be trivially copy constructed?  Can mutex be trivially copy assigned?  Even if the answer isn't portable, these latter questions can be portably asked and clearly answered, resulting in portable code.

Comment: What exactly is `is_trivially_copy_constructible` useful for? It doesn't by itself warrant byte-wise copies. In fact, advising `is_trivially_copy_constructible` instead of `is_trivially_copyable` may be dangerous, because people could (spuriously) deduce that `memcpy`'ing is fine if the copy constructor is trivial.

Comment: @Columbo:  I've attempted to clarify with an example.

Comment: @HowardHinnant `memcpy`ing into uninitialized memory does not create an object. That has to be done via placement `new`, and if so, you can go ahead and use the copy constructor right away (which potentially outperforms your method). I do agree, however, that the requirement of a trivial destructor is not justified when copying between identical types.

Comment: @Columbo:  The tricky part here is understanding that the standard is not always right.  Changing it to become "more correct" is a never ending, slow and laborious process.  If the standard was always right, it would be ok to `memcpy atomic<int>`. :-)

Comment: @HowardHinnant If you read my comment closely, you'll find that I just agreed on that (and reading defect reports every day, I am well aware of this). :-) However, `memcpy` doesn't create an object, and that may well be exploited by optimizers. That's a practical issue that is correctly reflected in P0137.

Comment: I like using `test()` as a private static member function defined in-class (I call it `assert_traits()` usually), so that I can look at the class semantics at its point of definition. The `static_asserts` work because a class is considered complete inside member definitions.

Answer (score 4):

Not all implementations provide a nontrivial destructor for `mutex`.  See libstdc++ (and assume that `__GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT` has been defined):

```
  // Common base class for std::mutex and std::timed_mutex
  class __mutex_base
  {
  // […]
#ifdef __GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT
    __native_type  _M_mutex = __GTHREAD_MUTEX_INIT;

    constexpr __mutex_base() noexcept = default;
#else
  // […]

    ~__mutex_base() noexcept { __gthread_mutex_destroy(&_M_mutex); }
#endif
  // […]
  };

  /// The standard mutex type.
  class mutex : private __mutex_base
  {
    // […]
    mutex() noexcept = default;
    ~mutex() = default;

    mutex(const mutex&) = delete;
    mutex& operator=(const mutex&) = delete;
  };
```

This implementation of `mutex` is both standard conforming and trivially copyable (which can be verified [via Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dcf3d33f97b9b7f0)). Similarly, nothing stops an implementation from keeping `condition_variable` trivially destructible (cf. [[thread.condition.condvar]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/thread.condition.condvar#6), although I couldn't find an implementation that does).

The bottom line is that we need clear, normative guarantees, and not clever, subtle interpretations of what `condition_variable` does or doesn't have to do (and how it has to accomplish that).

Comment: I asked the same question in the other answer, but doesn't the presence of `~mutex();` in the standard specify that the destructor shouldn't be defaulted, or is this just an example of what the class interface might look like?

Comment: Have edited the question to demonstrate the root of my possible misunderstanding.

Comment: @JosephThomson No, that is not implied. See [\[functions.within.classes\]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/functions.within.classes#1).

Answer (score 3):

It's important to look at this from a language lawyer perspective.

It's basically impossible for an implementation to implement `mutex`, condition variables, and the like in a way that leaves them trivially copyable. At some point, you have to write a destructor, and that destructor is very likely going to have to do non-trivial work.

But that doesn't matter. Why? Because the standard does not explicitly state that such types will not be trivially copyable. And therefore it is, from the perspective of the standard, *theoretically possible* for such objects to be trivially copyable.

Even though no functional implementation every can be, the point of N4460 is to make it very clear that such types will never be trivially copyable.

Comment: I am not sure if they actually took the correct appoach here. In my view, the correct approach would be to deem types with deleted assignment operators/copy ctors as **non**-trivially copyable. Yes, it breaks some backward compatibility, but it's the **right thing**. If something can't be copied with `operator=`, why is it legal to be copied with `memcpy()`?

Comment: But doesn't the standard specify a user-provided destructor for these types?

Comment: @JosephThomson: It specifies that there is a destructor; the type must be `Destructibe`. But nothing in the standard requires that destructor to be non-trivial. Again, think like a language lawyer; there "ain't no rule", so it's possible.

Comment: @SergeyA: "*Yes, it breaks some backward compatibility*" As far as the committee is concerned, that's the end of it right there. The trivially copyable rules and the various rules around defaulted/deleted member functions were not intended to change existing behavior.

Comment: @SergeyA Maybe so you can still move movable but uncopyable objects with `std::memcpy`?

Comment: @JosephThomson, there is no such thing as 'TriviallyMovable'. So to analyze movable objects one need to check for trivial move constructor.

Comment: @NicolBolas I figured `~mutex();` meant the destructor shouldn't be deleted or defaulted, since defaulting or deleting seems to affect the compile-time interface of the class (e.g. trivial copyability). If this isn't the case, therein lies my confusion. Is this specified anywhere in the standard, or is it just left to interpretation?

Comment: @SergeyA True, but then they would need to add the "trivially movable" concept to the standard if they wanted to allow `std::memcpy` optimization for move-only types. Not that it would be a bad thing.

Comment: @JosephThomson: The standard specifies *behavior*, not implementation. Since it ascribes no specific behavior to `~mutex` with regard to triviality, then the particular behavior is up to the individual implementations.

Comment: @NicolBolas It seem to specify use of the default implementation (`= default;`) in a lot of cases. Can implementations choose to provide their own implementation instead if it has the same behaviour?

Comment: Have edited the question to demonstrate the root of my possible misunderstanding.